# Multiple Web Applications - Same VM vs Multiple VMs

Tags: nginx, virtualbox

Firstly, I am more of a dev than admin. And I have always asked questions here. But please let me know if there is a better place to ask this question.

Here's my situation. I have an application that is built to run on linux. It serves both https (on port 443 using nginx) and ssh (on port 22). But due to organizational restrictions, I am forced to run it on a windows host with a linux guest using virtual box. Also, there is another web application on the host box; both these web applications should be served based on the URL (example: app1.com, app2.com). URLs need to be preserved. All ssh traffic can default to guest.

> One idea I have to make this work is below, and I would like to know
> if I am making this more complicated than it should be. Any help is appreciated.

**Steps:**

1. Use an unused port for https (say 8443) on my host and redirect all
   traffic to the guest. Use NAT based port forwarding (8443 -> 443, 22 -> 22)
   in Virtualbox.
2. The only thing left would be to setup another nginx on
   the host as a reverse proxy.  Set up virtual hosts on windows
   (/etc/hosts) and have the two IP and URL entries (app1.com and app2.com).
   Use a separate nginx on the host as a reverse proxy to redirect app1 traffic
   to the web app on the host and app2 traffic to 8443.

> **Questions:**
>
> 1. Can I avoid the extra nginx reverse proxy on the host while preserving the  URL?
> 2. Also what about ssl. Can I just set up https on the host and route it to port 80 on guest and avoid having two certs? Note: I am using NAT in Virtualbox, so there should not be any security issues I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is an administration question, and the user posted the identical question to serverfault, where it was answered: https://serverfault.com/questions/835220/multiple-web-applications-same-vm-vs-multiple-vms

Comment: Yes, I asked the same question there, and got a response.